# Laravel Continuous Deployment with GitHub webhook

Tags: ubuntu, github, npm

I have a Laravel application on a Ubuntu server running nginx.

I want to setup a CD system like Netlify has for static sites, so that on each `git push` the server should automatically `pull` and run the `build` scripts, which would be quite cool .

I setup a GitHub webhook so that on every push it triggers a bash script named `deploy.sh` on the server.

This is my `deploy.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# activate maintenance mode
php artisan down

# update source code
git pull

npm run build

# update PHP dependencies
#composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist

php artisan migrate --force

php artisan up
```

So far so good.

But the script fails at the `npm run build` script, and I get this output:

```
> npm run production

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! path sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! @ build: `npm run production`
npm ERR! spawn sh ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

When I run the script in the terminal [through ssh] manually, it works, even as the `www-data` user!

I tested running it as the `www-data` user by running `sudo -H -u www-data ./deploy.sh` and it worked!
So I'm baffled as to why it fails when triggered by the webhook [which runs as user `www-data` which I confirmed by putting `whoami` in the script]...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm trying to figure this out a long time already...

Comment: me too looking for a similar answer.